# User keeps changing question markup to use HTML markup

Tags: discussion, specific-edit, rollback-wars

While looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62044939)'s revision history, I've noticed that there's a user who goes by the name [Alex Skorkin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312771/alex-skorkin) who has edited the contents of a question to use HTML markup instead of the standard Markdown markup:

[image: Screenshot of the revision history of a question on StackOverflow]

This same user has been persistently editing the question to use HTML markup instead of the standard Markdown markup, despite my efforts to attempt to roll back the question to the revision before the HTML markup was added:

[image: Screenshot of Revision 7 from the revision history of a question on StackOverflow]

However, looking at this user's [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/users/312771/alex-skorkin?tab=activity&sort=revisions), it seems that they have done this redundant editing before on multiple questions.

What should I do? Is my rolling back of the question justified?

Comment: Don't engage in an edit war, instead custom moderator flag the post and let the moderators sort out what should happen.

Comment: I've locked the post and linked here.

Comment: @SamuelLiew I don't think the post should be unlocked as the user has since re-edited the question to re-add the HTML markup again in [revision 11](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62044939/11), which was done 5 minutes after the post was unlocked.

Comment: @SamuelLiew he also did it for the other post you unlocked too: https://stackoverflow.com/q/62035056/8620333

Comment: It seems that this user is automatically editing (using a tool) all "testcafe" related question to automatically add tags. This should not be allowed at all. Edits should be done by a *human* not a *machine*

Comment: I'm in bed now, but have blocked further edits for the time being. Please help to roll back any posts that needs it.

Comment: It looks like that person has been doing this HTML thing since at least [March 16](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/60566816/revisions). There's a lot of edits to look at.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you for pointing this out. I apologize for any inconvenience these edits have caused. I will not perform edits in such a manner anymore.

Comment: I wish more Meta disputes ended this amicably.

Comment: Maybe it is my curiosity but can you elaborate why you made these edits? If you feel that is none of my or our business then ignore this request.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the edits. (P.S. Just curious, but is there a reason why the automated software you're (possibly) using modifies the markup to an HTML form as well? And your automated software has re-edited the question _again_ to include the HTML markup - see [revision 11 of the same question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62044939/11).)

Comment: I don't think this answer is beneficial enough to resolve the issue - they have once again revised the question ([revision 11](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/62044939/11)) to re-add the HTML markup.

Comment: you will get banned if you continue such edits ... why are you still editing if you said *i will not perform edits in such manner anymore* ?

Comment: Guess now we'll only know the true reason behind these edits after a month.

Comment: Either that, or the suspension was to stop the edits while the mods work out whatever actually happened. Considering they were last seen 2 hours ago (in spite of editing an hour ago; yes, there's a discrepancy between last seen and when someone actually was last on the site, but it's a decent indicator in this case), it's likely an automated system

Comment: "in such a manner" ...  sounds to me like he thought tweaking his script was enough to silence this op ...  He shouldn't be using a script to edit *anything*

Comment: @DanRayson A script is fine to use, if it's being helpful. The user, however, is ultimately responsible for the edits which are made by their account, regardless of what tools were or were not used. [Disclosure: I, and many people, routinely use scripts to aid in making edits. Scripts can be quite helpful in correcting common errors (e.g. spelling, grammar, basic formatting, etc.).]

Comment: @Makyen but I don't think a script that automatically add tags is a good thing. You need to know the context of the question to be able to add tags. A script can never do this and I don't think there is an tag that should always be added with another (if it's the case, then we should make one of them a synonym)

Comment: @TemaniAfif unless you're dealing with a burnination preprocessing phase (notably excel-vba => excel + vba) or want to manually fix tag implication (i.e. python3 implies python, java8 implies java. There are obviously exceptions. Without having seen the tags, I'd guess catch and catch2 (C++ testing library) wouldn't make sense to imply together because they're technically two very different versions. There's still a lot of cases where there is implication). Tag implication as a system would cut down on that, but we don't have that.

Comment: There's also tags that have extremely few valid uses together - notably IDE tags and language tags. As an example, there's very few legitimate questions where both  [android] and [android-studio] make sense. IDE tag abuse is a whole different can of worms though

Comment: @TemaniAfif I made no comment about the specifics of what any script was doing. I was arguing *only* against the blanket statement: "he shouldn't be using a script to edit *anything*". For editing, my opinion is we should usually be discussing the benefit or harm which is being done by an edit or group of edits, rather than blanket statements about the tools which may, or may not, have been used to make the edit. Obviously, there are some exceptions, as with almost everything. As to a script adjusting question tags, that can be good or bad, depending on what's being done and its context.

Comment: @Makyen: What kind of edits? What about false positives? Shouldn't you manually check every change?

Comment: @PeterMortensen Personally, I review every portion of every edit prior to the edit being saved. It's not uncommon for me to either undo (within the edit interface, prior to saving) what the script does, or even just cancel the edit entirely and start over. Generally, I find that it's difficult to anticipate in code all the possible ways which a human might do something, either right or wrong. However, other than the statement that the user is responsible for any edits which are made by their account, I don't feel most blanket statements are appropriate.